# Function ngOnChanges() is not working in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngonchanges

I'm trying to call function `ngOnChanges()` in my Angular 5.x component whenever the variable `this.test` in component lifecycle or in template is changed but it's not working, `ngOnChanges()` function is not called anytime. Please can someone help me?

src/app.ts:

```
import {Component, NgModule, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Test field" value="{{ test }}">
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnChanges {
  @Input() test: string;
  name: string;
  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log('ngOnChanges');

    if (changes.test && !changes.test.isFirstChange()) {
      // exteranl API call or more preprocessing...
    }

    for (let propName in changes) {
      let change = changes[propName];
      console.dir(change);
      if(change.isFirstChange()) {
        console.log(`first change: ${propName}`);
      } else {
        console.log(`prev: ${change.previousValue}, cur: ${change.currentValue}`);
      }
    }
  }


}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Live preview: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZHFOXFhEkSv2f1U3lehv

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm seeing Template parse errors in your linked plunker. It doesn't like your `ngModel` usage

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Input properties provide a mechanism for a parent component to pass data to a child component. They are NOT meant to pass data from a template to its component.

And only changes to that input property defined by the PARENT generate the onChanges method.

I updated the plunker to fix the missing FormsModule and add a child component to demonstrate how to use the input property and onChanges lifecycle hook:

https://plnkr.co/edit/1JF0wV28HnjXDZxMSifY?p=preview

**Child Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-child',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="test" placeholder="Test field">
    </div>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() test: string;
  name: string;
  constructor() {  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log('in ngOnChanges');
    if (changes.test && !changes.test.isFirstChange()) {
      // exteranl API call or more preprocessing...
    }

    for (let propName in changes) {
      let change = changes[propName];
      console.dir(change);
      if(change.isFirstChange()) {
        console.log(`first change: ${propName}`);
      } else {
        console.log(`prev: ${change.previousValue}, cur: ${change.currentValue}`);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Parent component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <my-child [test]='parentTest'></my-child>
      <button (click)='onClick()'>Change Value</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  parentTest: string;
  name: string;
  counter = 1;

  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

  onClick() {
    this.parentTest = `test: ${this.counter}`;
    this.counter++;
  }
}
```

To catch changes from the template in the template's component, use a setter instead:

```
  // To catch changes from the template
  _test: string;
  get test(): string {
    return this._test;
  }

  @Input()
  set test(value: string) {
    this._test = value;
    console.log("Textbox value changed: " + this._test);
  }
```

Or you can use Sajeetharan's suggestion to catch the template's change in its associated template. It will also work.

Answer (score 5):

What you need here is ngModelChange not ngOnChanges

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Test field" (ngModelChange)="printVal()">
```

and then

```
printVal(){
  //detect model change here
}
```

**`ngOnChanges`** works over  @input event emitter

Comment: can you please help me to fix this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50166996/ngonchanges-not-get-triggered-in-angular4